# Using Guzzle to fetch xml simple_xml_load returns strange result - large file

Tags: php, xml

```
    $res = $client->get( 'https://****', ['auth' =>  ['****', '****']] );
$statusCode = $res->getStatusCode();
// Check that the res is successful.
if ($statusCode >= 200 && $statusCode < 300)
 {
  $xml = $res->xml();
  //save the feed as a file
  $xml->asXML('myfile.xml');
 }

//load the contents of the file again 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');
```

file definitely has xml in it and is about 6mb

pretty print r prints out this only

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [generation-date] => 2015-03-16T23:56:26.972+01:00
            [error-occurred] => false
        )

)
```

any idea what the problem is?
$xml->children() does nothing.

Comment: You should look into the file with something like Notepad++ or the like.

Comment: `print_r/var_dump` is misleading. it looks like its missing but its really there, those dumping functions wont give justice to whats really inside your XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't include the namespace when  I looped through

e.g. 
I was doing

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $item){
//...
}
```

but needed to do

```
foreach ($xml->children('namespace-url-info-here') as $item){
//...
}
```

The namespace info was in the root element of the xml.